# How to get unreachable nodes after ansible playbook execution in python?

Tags: ansible, ansible-runner

After executing an ansible playbook, I need the node names that were not reached. I thought about using `AnsibleRunner` for running the ansible-playbook and I know of the special variables `ansible_play_hosts` and `ansible_play_hosts_all` which you can diff to get the unreachable nodes. But those special variables only exist in the context of ansible.

So how do I get the unreachable nodes from `AnsibleRunner` (or a similar utility), without parsing ansible's output.

**On Runner Objects**

Currently I am creating a runner object and evaluating its variables after execution. I see that in the events I can theoretically look for unreachable nodes, but that seems to be quite sketchy.

One might also be able to write an event handler that specifically catches those events that indicate that a node is unreachable that handles those cases differently.

I also wrote a small fact registration that registers which nodes are unreachable which will be executed as a last task, but I couldn't access it yet:

```
- set_fact:
    unreachable: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|difference(ansible_play_hosts) }}"
```

**On ansible API**

The ansible API has in its example a dictionary called `host_unreachable`. While that sounds very promising I have two issues with it: I) I couldn't run the example II) The API will not be downwards compatible and therefore shouldn't be used externally.

Comment: The first idea that came to my mind was: have ansible write that info somewhere (a file, a memory cache, a database, a topic/queue....) before it exists and read the info from there. Then I overlooked the [documentation](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and I'm quite sure the way to go is parsing the [runner events](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python_interface/#runner-events)

Comment: See [Example 3: Handle custom status of playbook](https://ansible-runner-role.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example3-status.html).

Comment: If someone would elaborate a little on their suggested solution I would be glad. I will be updating the question with what I have learned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is actually available out of the box in the [`Runner.stats` property](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ansible_runner/#ansible_runner.runner.Runner.stats) once your playbook has run.

Example implementation

Given:

1. the `inv.yml` inventory

```yaml
 ---
 local_test:
   vars:
     ansible_connection: local
     failling_hosts:
       - test2
       - test3
   hosts:
     test1:
     test2:
     test3:
     test4:
 
 unreachable:
   hosts:
     test5:
```

2. the `test.yml` playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: all

  tasks:
    - name: dummy task for all
      debug:
        msg: task1 for all hosts

    - name: blindly fail some hosts for test
      assert:
        that: inventory_hostname not in (failling_hosts | d([]))

    - name: dummy task for survivors
      debug:
        msg: task2 for survivors
```

3. the `test.py` python script

```py
import ansible_runner

runner = ansible_runner.run(
    private_data_dir='.',
    inventory='inv.yml',
    playbook='test.yml',
    quiet=False if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == '-v' else True
)

overall_failed = {
    'unreachable': runner.stats['dark'].keys(),
    'failed': runner.stats['failures'].keys()
}

for elem_type, elements in overall_failed.items():
    for i, host in enumerate(elements):
        if i == 0:
            print(f'\nList of {elem_type} hosts:')
        print(f'\t{host}')
```

We get (run with `-v` if you want the playbook output too):

```
$ python test.py

List of unreachable hosts:
    test5

List of failed hosts:
    test2
    test3
```

Comment: I will test and confirm this on Monday. This sounds very promising.

Comment: This works like a charm. Given that stats["dark] returns a dictionary with the nodes as key and 1 as the value: What meaning does the '1' carry? I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: It's the number of "events". It does have much sense for unreachable as it should only be one anyway. Nuber of changes of ok task is probably more meaningful.